# ARIA attributes in IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, wai-aria

I'm trying to set the `aria-autocomplete` attribute on an element using jQuery. However when **IE10** is running in either **IE5 Quirks mode** or **IE7 Standards mode** it produces a `Member not found` error.

```
<input type="textbox" id="test" />​
$('#test').attr({"aria-autocomplete": "list"});​
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poztin/LaEJS/4/) for a demo.

I have tried various other ARIA attributes as defined here:

[HTML 5: The Markup Language (ARIA Edition)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/aria/aria.html)

Some produce the same error, others do not.

I can't reproduce the error in IE9.

**Is this a bug in IE10? jQuery? Or is there some other reason for this that I'm not understanding?**

Comment: jQuery does not support quirks mode. I'm not sure about IE7 Standards mode in IE10. I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Poz,

This is a known bug in the IE10 browser when in compatibility mode. Please up-vote this bug ticket to increase the likelihood that it will be fixed. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/774078 The ticket was submitted by the jQuery team.

Have you tried your code sample in real IE7? I tried your jsFiddle with browserstack (WinXP/IE7) and the example worked without an error.

If you were using compatibility mode to simulate testing IE7, then the good news is that using native IE7 works just fine. The bad news is there is a bug in IE10 compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks Elijah. I've upvoted the bug. I only tested IE7 using the IE10 dev tools so that should be ok then.

Comment: @Elijah_Manor - that link is broken. Would you mind to please provide another so I can upvote it.?.? Thanks

Comment: @johntrepreneur - The link is not broken.  If you cannot see it, you'll need to register with the site and join the IE Feedback Program.  The comments on the jQuery bug make it seem like you only need to register.

Comment: link doesn't work for me: The content that you requested cannot be found or you do not have permission to view it.

Comment: Microsoft has postponed any fix for this problem.  As IE-11 is now out, it may be postponed forever...

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me. In the version of Jquery that you are using, in my cas (`jquery-1.7.2.js`) there is one section around line 2764 that is like this:

```
// Use this for any attribute in IE6/7
// This fixes almost every IE6/7 issue
nodeHook = jQuery.valHooks.button = {
    get: function( elem, name ) {
        var ret;
        ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
        return ret && ( fixSpecified[ name ] ? ret.nodeValue !== "" : ret.specified ) ?
            ret.nodeValue :
            undefined;
    },
    set: function( elem, value, name ) {
        // Set the existing or create a new attribute node
        var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
        if ( !ret ) {
            ret = document.createAttribute( name );
            elem.setAttributeNode( ret );
        }
        return ( ret.nodeValue = value + "" );
    }
};
```

Acoording to https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12577, it's a problem of compability of IE10 in IE7 mode. the solution is to change the return variable in set function:

```
 return ( ret.nodeValue = value + "" );
//for:
elem.setAttribute(name, value + ""); 
return (ret.value);
```